# Как после каждого слова текста, которое заканчивается заданной подстрокой, вставить заданное слово?

Tags: java

Есть кусок кода, но он делает не то что надо, а надо именно чтобы код изменял текст следующим образом: после каждого слова текста, которое заканчивается заданной подстрокой, вставить заданное слово

```
    package com.company;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text ="Some text";
    String string = "Hi";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k = s.nextInt();
    s.close();
    String splited[] = text.split("[.]");
    for(int i=0;i<splited.length;i++)
    {
        splited[i]= new StringBuffer(splited[i]).insert(k, string).toString();
        System.out.println(splited[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: уберите из вопроса код. который к вопросу не относится, и добавьте тот, что относится.

Answer (score 2):

```
String suffix = "ing";
String text = "ME!";

String lorem = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. " +
            "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled " +
            "it to make a type specimen book. Typesetting. Typesetting";

System.out.println(lorem.replaceAll("(" + suffix + ")\\s*?", "$1 " + text));

>>>> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing ME! and typesetting ME! industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. Typesetting ME!. Typesetting ME!
```

Answer (score 1):

Не самое изящное решение, но работает:

```
        import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String suffix = s.nextLine(); // вводим строку на которую должно заканчиваться слово
        s.close();
        String text = "Some text";
        String string = "Hi";
        String splited[] = text.split("\\s"); // разделяем все слова в тексте по пробелу
        StringBuffer newText = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
            if (!splited[i].endsWith(suffix)) // проверяем оканчивается ли слово заданной подстрокой
            {
                newText.append(splited[i] + " ");
            } else {
                newText.append(splited[i] + " " + string + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает